# C++ function chain returning function

Tags: c++, function

First of all sorry for the not so clear title, it is far easier to explain it with code:

Given a function prototype like this:

```
auto sum(int a){
      ... 
}
```

I want to be able to use it in this way:

```
add(3) == 3 //true
add(1)(2)(3) == 6 //true
```

I'm just trying to do this for personal knowledge, so I would appreciate more if someone would indicate me which constructs I should study to achieve this (I'm pretty sure I have to use std::function, but I don't know how) , rather than giving me the plain solution.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Note that whatever `add(1)` returns has to be both comparable with (or, in the general case, convertible to) an `int`, and also callable. The only way to achieve both is to use an object that overloads `operator int` and `operator()`. That should get you going :)

Comment: How about just use `ellipsis` and call it a day.

Comment: Are `sum(int a)` and `add(int b)` supposed to be the same function? Others have already gone forward with this assumption but it would be nice to see the question edited to have the same function name if that's what you intended... Or is there a reason you used `add` in the 2nd code block, implying that `add` is some sort of wrapper for `sum` ?

Answer (score 3):

May not be exact answer, but you can try this way:

```
class foo {
    int data = 0;
public:
    foo& operator()(int i) { data += i; return *this; }
    bool operator==(int i) { return this-> data == i; }
    void print() const { cout << data << endl; }
};

int main() {

    foo add;
    add(1)(2)(3);
    add.print();
    cout <<  (add(3) == 9 ?  "Same" : "Not same") << endl;
}
```